How to approximate general normal operators with diagonal ones
Suppose we call a normal operator $A\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ nice if its induces an eigen-decomposition of the Hilbert space $H$.

Question 1. Are nice normal operators exactly those whose spectrum consists of only eigenvalues and cluster points of eigenvalues?


Question 2. Is every normal operator $A\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ a limit point of some net of nice normal operators under the WOT (or some other topology)?

I'm trying to see if this is a correct intuition for understanding the general spectrum theorem. Thanks in advance.
Update. On second thought, what I mean by nice normal operators are just diagonal normal ones. Since, if $H=\oplus_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)}H_\lambda$, where $H_\lambda=\text{Ker}\left(A-\lambda\right)$, then for any orthonormal basis $B:=\{e_i: i\in I\}$, every $e_i$ belongs to one $H_\lambda$, for some eigenvalue $\lambda$, and thus $A(e_i)=\lambda e_i$ . Since I also assumed boundedness, then we should also have $\|A\|=\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in \sigma_p(A)\}<\infty$.

To Q2: a bounded normal operator is even the limit of a sequence of "nice" normal operators in the operator norm topology (if i understand correctly what you mean by "induces an eigen-decomposition", maybe you could elaborate on that part). This is essentially what the spectral theorem says.

@jd27 By "nice", I just mean the invariant subspaces corresponding to the eigenvalues span the entire space, not just a proper subspace. So $H=\oplus_{\lambda\in \sigma_p(A)}H_\lambda$.

@jd27 On second thought, it seems the "nice" normal operators are just diagonal normal operators. So What I'm asking is can a general normal one bounded be approximated by diagonal normal ones, without applying unitary equivalence.
